# Sample Random Column for Each Row in Data.Frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a `data.frame` that has time series values for `a`, `b`, and `c`. I would like to build a random time series that randomly picks the value of the columns for each row (i.e. date).

So for example, if we have the following `df`:

```
df <- data.frame(date = c(as.Date("2018-08-01"),as.Date("2018-09-01"), as.Date("2018-10-01")), a = c(1.0, 1.5, 1.8), b=c(-1.0, -2.0, 3.0), c=c(-2.0, -15.0, 1.7))

 #> df
 #           date   a  b     c
 #   1 2018-08-01 1.0 -1  -2.0
 #   2 2018-09-01 1.5 -2 -15.0
 #   3 2018-10-01 1.8  3   1.7
```

A possible random sample would look like (in this case picked `a` for the first month, `b` for the second, and `c` for the third).

```
df.random.sample <- data.frame(date = c(as.Date("2018-08-01"),as.Date("2018-09-01"), as.Date("2018-10-01")), random = c(1.0, -2.0, 1.7))

#> df.random.sample
#        date random
#1 2018-08-01    1.0
#2 2018-09-01   -2.0
#3 2018-10-01    1.7
```

Most importantly, I have many different columns so would like this to work with column indexes so I do not need to specify each column name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we want to sample by row, then use `apply`

```
cbind(df[1], random = apply(df[-1], 1, sample, size = 1))
```

---

Or use a vectorized approach with `row/column` indexing

```
cbind(df[1], random = df[-1][cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), sample(2:ncol(df))-1)])
```

Comment: I'm getting `Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows` when I try using my data.frame that is exact same format but the number of cols does not match the number of rows.

Comment: @cpage Have you tried the second solution with `apply`

Comment: @arkun that seems to work, what is the difference between the first and the second. Specifically, what is "if it is by row" referring to?

Comment: @cpage Because the data is kind of symmetric (with respect to number of rows and the number of columns (if we remoce the 'date'), I was thinking that we need to get the `sample` of length from each column.  But reading the quesiton, it was mentioned that you need for each row, select one of the column values. from 'a', 'b' or 'c' Is that what you wanted

Comment: what would you add to keep the source name of the random column as a new variable per row?