# How to select randomly rows and columns in each row in a list

Tags: r, list, random, lapply, sample

I have a list in which there is a 5x5 matrix data set. I want to randomly select 2 rows and within each row I want to select 3 elements not necessarily from same columns.

So, I generated three data sets and made a list. I was able to select 2 rows randomly but have a difficulty in selecting 3 elements randomly not selecting columns.

Here is my code.

```
    ### Generate three data sets
    dat1 <- (matrix(rnorm(25), ncol=5))
    dat2 <- (matrix(rnorm(25), ncol=5))
    dat3 <- (matrix(rnorm(25), ncol=5))

    all.dat <- list(dat1=dat1, dat2=dat2, dat3=dat3)
    all.dat

    #$`dat1`
    #           [,1]      [,2]       [,3]        [,4]       [,5]
    #[1,]  1.4394742 0.7064418 -1.3472468  0.52847179 -0.7642337
    #[2,]  0.2490570 0.7510308 -0.7028238 -0.09730666 -0.6340773
    #[3,]  0.8981850 0.7592610  0.9139721 -0.45700647 -0.2727481
    #[4,] -1.0467119 0.2147032 -3.2104254 -0.17797056  0.8897180
    #[5,] -0.5437118 0.5803862 -0.1814992  1.93316139 -1.3708932

    #$dat2
    #          [,1]       [,2]          [,3]         [,4]       [,5]
    #[1,] 1.0442187 -1.4156893  0.5606035101 -1.350030718  0.1538721
    #[2,] 0.2080905 -1.7748005  0.8620324724 -0.169071336 -1.7537700
    #[3,] 0.9153835 -0.9884572 -1.7279901136 -1.334516414  0.5773021
    #[4,] 0.1359423 -1.5107088 -1.4289650078 -0.002001498 -0.4712699
    #[5,] 0.1695023 -0.7315209 -0.0003996577 -1.043326258  1.2939485

    #$dat3
    #           [,1]        [,2]         [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
    #[1,] -1.4994878 -0.59179084  0.998017255  1.4021344  0.5929842
    #[2,]  0.3424003  1.33568858  2.214968765 -0.2434351  1.3588000
    #[3,] -1.0117892  0.91065720 -0.761932994 -0.8117838 -0.4094731
    #[4,] -0.1694781 -0.02937177 -0.826337270  0.2178774 -0.6427046
    #[5,]  0.3413101 -0.56911900  0.001363063  0.5579126 -0.9373204

    ### Select rows and columns.
    all.dat.sel.1 <- 
    lapply(all.dat, function(x) {
    x[sample(nrow(x), size = 2), sample(ncol(x), size = 3)]
    })

    all.dat.sel.1

    #$`dat1`
    #           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
    #[1,] -0.4570065  0.8981850 -0.2727481
    #[2,]  1.9331614 -0.5437118 -1.3708932

    #$dat2
    #              [,1]         [,2]       [,3]
    #[1,] -0.0003996577 -1.043326258  1.2939485
    #[2,] -1.4289650078 -0.002001498 -0.4712699

    #$dat3
    #           [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
    #[1,] -1.4994878 1.4021344  0.9980173
    #[2,] -0.1694781 0.2178774 -0.8263373
```

Then, I was able to select rows randomly but elements in each row were from the same columns. For example, values, -1.4994878 in row 1 and -0.1694781 in row 2 were from column 1 in dat3.

What I would like to have is something like this:

```
    #$dat3
    #           [,1]        [,2]         [,3]
    #[1,] -1.4994878 0.998017255    0.5929842
    #[4,]  0.2178774 -0.02937177 -0.826337270
```

There is an example of this (`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53095050/sample-random-column-for-each-row-in-data-frame`). However, it applied to data frame not list data.

Comment: Do you want to sample *any* 2*3 elements from each matrix? or do the results row elements need to be from the same original matrix row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take advantage of the fact that a matrix is a folded vector, meaning, a vector with a `dim` attribute and sample 2*3 vector elements directly.

```
lapply(all.dat, function(x){
    matrix(sample(x, 2*3), nrow = 2)
})

#$dat1
#           [,1]       [,2]        [,3]
#[1,]  0.5060559 -0.5644520 -0.83717168
#[2,] -0.6937202 -0.4771927  0.06445882
#
#$dat2
#          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
#[1,] -0.709440 -1.340993 0.5747557
#[2,] -1.068643  1.449496 1.1022975
#
#$dat3
#          [,1]      [,2]         [,3]
#[1,] 0.6482866 0.5630558 -0.007604756
#[2,] 0.6565885 1.3295648 -0.669633580
```

**Note:**  I have started the script with the call `set.seed(1234)`.

**Edit.**

After reading the [comment by user @Ronak Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56882100/how-to-select-randomly-rows-and-columns-in-each-row-in-a-list/56882305#comment100312802_56882305), and the question again, the code below might be what the OP is looking for. It's similar but not the same as Ronak's solution. Once again, the RNG seed was set to `1234` before the data creation code.

```
lapply(all.dat, function(x){
    t(apply(x[sample(nrow(x), 2), ], 1, sample, size = 3))
})
#$dat1
#           [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
#[1,] -0.4771927 -1.207066  0.5060559
#[2,] -0.4405479  1.084441 -0.9111954
#
#$dat2
#           [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
#[1,]  1.1022975 -0.9685143  1.449496
#[2,] -0.2942939 -0.5012581 -0.280623
#
#$dat3
#           [,1]         [,2]     [,3]
#[1,] -0.3665239 -0.773353424 1.367827
#[2,]  0.3364728 -0.007604756 2.070271
```

Comment: but this doesn't get data from same 2 random rows. It gets data from complete matrix but I am not sure if this is OP's requirement.

Comment: @RonakShah I really don't know, will ask the OP.

Comment: I had it wrong earlier I think. OP mentions `I want to randomly select 2 rows and within each row I want to select 3 elements not necessarily from same columns.`

Comment: This is exactly what I want! I do want to get them (rows or columns) without replacement (replace = F). Original data has 1000 data sets in a list with 20 x 1000 matrix in each data set. Thanks all of you for helps!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is

```
row_const <- 2
col_const <- 3

lapply(all.dat, function(x) {
    rand_rows <- sample(nrow(x), size = row_const)
    t(sapply(rand_rows, function(y) sample(x[y, ], col_const)))
})

#$dat1
#           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
#[1,] 0.07050839 -0.6868529  0.7013559
#[2,] 0.40077145 -1.0260044 -1.9666172

#$dat2
#           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
#[1,] -0.3059627 -1.138137 2.1689560
#[2,] -0.2950715  0.837787 0.5539177

#$dat3
#          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
#[1,] 0.3796395 -0.4910312  0.2533185
#[2,] 0.9222675  0.1238542 -1.0185754
```

It first selects two random rows from the each matrix and then selects 3 random elements from each row.

**data**

```
set.seed(123)
dat1 <- (matrix(rnorm(25), ncol=5))
dat2 <- (matrix(rnorm(25), ncol=5))
dat3 <- (matrix(rnorm(25), ncol=5))
all.dat <- list(dat1=dat1, dat2=dat2, dat3=dat3)
```